# Reset and clock

Tags: digital-logic, reset

In digital circuits (combination & Sequential) which input holds more priority clock signal or a reset signal? suppose we give a input reset in an asynchronous counter then reset will wait for clock signal or it will immediately reset the count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An *asynchronous* reset will *always* be performed regardless of the state of the clock; a *synchronous* reset on the other hand requires a clock pulse before it will take effect. Most reset inputs on counters are asynchronous, but confirm this with the datasheet before assuming anything.